# Limit points of a set in topological space

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

For a subset S of a topological space X, let cl(S) denote the closure of S in X, and let $S' = \{x: x\in cl(S - \{x\}) \}$ denote the derived set of S. If A and B are subsets of X, which of the following statements are true?

I. $(A \cup B)' = A' \cup B'$
II. $(A \cap B)' = A' \cap B'$
III. If A' is empty, then A is closed in X
IV. If A is open in X, then A' is not empty

The answer says that S' is the set of boundary points of S, and therefore the correct statements are I and III. However, I have two questions:
1. Is there a quick way to visualize why S' is the set of boundary points of S?
2. Given the fact that S' is the set of boundary points, I agree with the reasonings on II, III, and IV. For I, however, I do have a counterexample: suppose A = (1, 3), B = (2, 4), and $(A \cup B)' = (1, 4)' = \{1, 4\}$, but $A' \cup B' = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$. How could you disprove my counterexample?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, $A'$ is the set of limit points of $A$ (indeed traditionally called the derievd set of $A$ as well). It's *not* the set of boundary points. It's all non-isolated points of $A$, plus all points in $\operatorname{cl}(A)\setminus A$ too. If there are boundary points of $A$ they will be in $A'$, but the converse need not hold, $A'$ can be much bigger.

Your example for I is false, supposing we're in the reals: $A=(1,3)$ implies $A'=[1,3]$ etc. so both sides equal $[1,4]$ in the end.
In fact it's a true statement, try to prove it.

II is false indeed, try $A=[1,2], B=[2,3]$ in the reals where $(A \cap B)' = \emptyset \neq \{2\} = A' \cap B'$ or the more extreme example of $A=\Bbb Q$, $B=\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q$, where $(A \cap B)' = \emptyset \neq \Bbb R = A' \cap B'$.

III is true, as $\operatorname{cl}(A)=A \cup A'$ in any space.

IV need not be true, e.g. $\{1\}$ in $\Bbb Z$ is a counterexample.